# List comprehension with dynamic variable attributes

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Generally, a list comprehension follows a following pattern:

```
my_list = [record for record in records_set]
```

It could be extended to, for example, the following expression, if record is a dictionary:

```
my_list = [(record['attribute_a'],record['attribute_b']) for record in records_set]
```

What if I want the list comprehension to take a list of attributes I want to extract from a record as an argument?

Lets say I have a list

```
attributes_list = ['attribute_a','attribute_b','attribute_c']
```

As a result of applying it to the list comprehension pattern, I want to get the following list comprehension as a result:

```
my_list = [(record['attribute_a'],record['attribute_b'],record['attribute_c']) for record in records_set]
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
my_list =  [tuple(record[attr] for attr in attributes_list) for record in records_set]
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing to do is use `operator.itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter
values_from = itemgetter(*attributes_list)
my_list = [values_from(record) for record in record_set]
```

This makes it easy to skip the list comprehension and use `map` instead.

```
my_list = list(map(itemgetter(*attributes_list), record_set))
```

(As usual, the call to `list` is necessary in Python 3, not Python 2.)

Comment: Note: In the listcomp, it's better to make the `itemgetter` once outside the listcomp and reuse it, as there is a cost to creating the getter over and over that should be avoided. `map` avoids that cost.

Comment: Do you know if that's still true in Python 3? Looking at the byte code in Python 2, it's clear that `itemgetter` is called repeatedly. It's less clear to me what, exactly, is going on in Python 3.

Comment: In Python 3 the listcomp is a closure, which is hiding it from the disassembler, but if you dig in, it still has to create the `itemgetter` every time before calling it. You could still one-line it efficiently, but in an ugly way with `[values_from(record) for values_from in (itemgetter(*attributes_list),) for record in record_set]` to match `map`'s behavior, but not really worth the ugly.

Comment: OK, figured it had something to do with that anonymous `listcomp` getting created.